# How to convert flat multi-branch data to hierarchical JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, tree

```
[
  {
    "id": "a",
    "pid": "a",
    "name": "AA",
  },
  {
    "id": "b",
    "pid": "a",
    "name": "BB",
  },
  {
    "id": "c",
    "pid": "a",
    "name": "CC",
  },
  {
    "id": "x",
    "pid": "b",
    "name": "XX",
  }
]
```

Above is the data I got from the database. Every person has an `id` and a `pid`, `pid` points to the person's higher level person's `id`. If a person has highest level, the `id` equals `pid`.

I want to convert the raw data to hierarchical JSON, like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "a",
    "name": "AA",
    "child": [
      {
        "id": "b",
        "name": "BB"
        "child": [
          {
            "id": "x",
            "name": "XX"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "c",
        "name": "CC"
      }
    ]  
  }
]
```

I'm using Node.js.

Comment: is the data sorted by id, or is it random ordered?

Comment: @NinaScholz It is random ordered, but IDs are unique.

Comment: how do you know the root of the tree? please add some more data for checking.

Comment: @NinaScholz When the `id` equals `pid`, he is the root.

Comment: I updated the question, thank you!@NinaScholz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to create a tree and take `id === pid` as a root for the tree, which works for unsorted data.

> How it works:
>
> Basically, for every object in the array, it takes the `id` for building a new object as `parentid` for a new object.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> { "id": 6, "pid": 4 }
> ```
>
> It generates this property first with `id`:
>
> ```
> "6": {
>     "id": 6,
>     "pid": 4
> }
> ```
>
> and then with `pid`:
>
> ```
> "4": {
>     "children": [
>         {
>             "id": 6,
>             "pid": 4
>         }
>     ]
> },
> ```
>
> and while all objects are similarly treated, we finally get a tree.
>
> If `id === pid`, the root node is found. This is the object for the later return.

```js
var data = [
        { "id": "f", "pid": "b", "name": "F" },
        { "id": "e", "pid": "c", "name": "E" },
        { "id": "d", "pid": "c", "name": "D" },
        { "id": "c", "pid": "b", "name": "C" },
        { "id": "a", "pid": "a", "name": "A" },
        { "id": "b", "pid": "a", "name": "B" }
    ],
    tree = function (data) {
        var r, o = Object.create(null);
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            a.children = o[a.id] && o[a.id].children;
            o[a.id] = a;
            if (a.id === a.pid) {
                r = a;
            } else {
                o[a.pid] = o[a.pid] || {};
                o[a.pid].children = o[a.pid].children || [];
                o[a.pid].children.push(a);
            }
        });
        return r;
    }(data);

console.log(tree);
```

Comment: Thank you! I know how to solve this kind of problem now!

Comment: It would worth mentioning that this brilliant algorithm takes the full benefit of objects being reference type in JS. This fact simply saves huge amount of sorting effort.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, the quote is my part, it is not copied from somewhere else.

Comment: @NinaScholz ok, just wanted to check if edit was reasonable. (I'd not use quote formatting for my own content unique to given post... but I don't think there is any strong guidance against it). (flag as "no longer needed" when read)

Answer (score 1):

Influenced by the answer of Nina, this is my resolution just for the record.

```js
function corrugate(data){
  var root = "";
  return data.reduce((t,o) => {
                            o.id === o.pid && (root = o.id);
                              t[o.id]  ? t[o.id].name = o.name
                                       : t[o.id] = {id: o.id, name: o.name};
                              t[o.pid] ? o.pid !== o.id ? t[o.pid].children.push(t[o.id])
                                                        : t[o.pid].children = t[o.pid].children || []
                                       : t[o.pid] = {id: o.pid, children: [t[o.id]]};
                              return t;
                              },{})[root];
}

var   data = [{ "id": "f", "pid": "b", "name": "F" },
              { "id": "e", "pid": "c", "name": "E" },
              { "id": "b", "pid": "a", "name": "B" },
              { "id": "d", "pid": "c", "name": "D" },
              { "id": "c", "pid": "b", "name": "C" },
              { "id": "a", "pid": "a", "name": "A" }
             ];
console.log(corrugate(data));
```