# Creating array of nested objects from array of non nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Suppose I have the following array:

```
[  
   {  
      'id':48,
      'parent':0,
      'order':1
   },
   {  
      'id':49,
      'parent':48,
      'order':2
   },
   {  
      'id':50,
      'parent':0,
      'order':3
   },
   {  
      'id':51,
      'parent':48,
      'order':4
   },
   {  
      'id':52,
      'parent':0,
      'order':5
   },
   {  
      'id':53,
      'parent':50,
      'order':6
   },
   {  
      'id':54,
      'parent':50,
      'order':7
   }
]
```

I need to write some javascript code either in an angular controller or using ng-repeat in the view that can produce the following output:

```
  [  
   {  
      'id':48,
      'parent':0,
      'order':1,
      'children':[  
         {  
            'id':49,
            'parent':48,
            'order':2
         },
         {  
            'id':51,
            'parent':48,
            'order':4
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      'id':50,
      'parent':0,
      'order':3,
      'children':[  
         {  
            'id':53,
            'parent':50,
            'order':6
         },
         {  
            'id':54,
            'parent':50,
            'order':7
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      'id':52,
      'parent':0,
      'order':5
   },

]
```

You can assume that the original array will be sorted by order already, however the output does have to maintain the order as well.

My current solution does work. I'm using ng-repeat with a conditional argument to check if the current object has a parent.

Essentially I'm using ng-repeat to output all the parents, then I loop through the entire array again for each parent checking for children. This has severe performance penalties and takes too long for any array over 40-50 objects long. Another downside is that for each depth, the performance penalties increase. I would like to include up to 5 nesting levels, but my looping system will not hold up.

Ideally, I would sort all this out in the controller, and then make ng-repeat do minimal work.

Did anyone actually read my current solution? Here it is, since I'm being accused of getting things for free *eye roll*

```
<div class="comments">
        <span></span>
        <ul>
            <li class="comment byuser comment-author-solopine bypostauthor even thread-even depth-1" id="comment-21">
                <span></span>
                <div class="thecomment">
                    <span></span>
                    <div class="author-img">
                        <span><img alt="" class="avatar avatar-60 photo" height="60" src="{{%20comment.author_avatar_urls['96']%20}}" width="60"></span>
                    </div><span></span>
                    <div class="comment-text">
                        <span><span class="reply"><a class="comment-reply-link scroll" href="" rel="nofollow">Reply</a></span></span>
                        <h6 class="author">{{ comment.author_name }}</h6><span class="date">{{ comment.date | date : 'longDate' }}</span>
                        <p></p>
                        <div></div>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li style="list-style: none">
                <span></span>
                <ul class="children">
                    <li class="comment byuser comment-author-solopine bypostauthor odd alt depth-2" id="comment-24">
                        <span></span>
                        <div class="thecomment">
                            <span></span>
                            <div class="author-img">
                                <span><img alt="" class="avatar avatar-60 photo" height="60" src="{{%20childComment.author_avatar_urls['96']%20}}" width="60"></span>
                            </div><span></span>
                            <div class="comment-text">
                                <span><span class="reply"><a class="comment-reply-link" href="" rel="nofollow">Reply</a></span></span>
                                <h6 class="author">{{ childComment.author_name }}</h6><span class="date">{{ childComment.date | date : 'longDate' }}</span>
                                <p></p>
                                <div></div>
                                <p></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li><!-- #comment-## -->
                </ul><!-- .children -->
                <!-- #comment-## -->
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

As I said, using ng-repeat.

Comment: Is there a reason for specifically saying you don't want vanilla JS?

Comment: Dear friend, SO is not get code for free site. Please share what you have achieved so far. Also if you spend sometime on google, you will find relevant answer.

Comment: It looks like you need a standard tree structure from flat array so there a lot of answers how to achieve that

Comment: How is this a get code "for free" request? I already have code and explained my method above. I'm doing it all in the HTML side

Comment: It can be done in vanilla JS. However it's not simply a how to do this, but more of a how to do this performantly question

Comment: Flat to nested is easy if you have the flat data sorted such that no parent comes after it's child. Then by reverse iteration, one by one attaching the children inside their parents and removing them from the flat array is a breeze. But if you don't have it sorted the best answer that i know is this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37806854/4543207

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You coud use an object for lookup and insert to the parent's children. adn to the node itself.

This proposal works only if the parent is inserted before the children.

```js
var data = [{ 'id': 48, 'parent': 0, 'order': 1 }, { 'id': 49, 'parent': 48, 'order': 2 }, { 'id': 50, 'parent': 0, 'order': 3 }, { 'id': 51, 'parent': 48, 'order': 4 }, { 'id': 52, 'parent': 0, 'order': 5 }, { 'id': 53, 'parent': 50, 'order': 6 }, { 'id': 54, 'parent': 50, 'order': 7 }],
    tree = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    this[a.id] = { id: a.id, parent: a.parent, order: a.order };
    this[a.parent].children = this[a.parent].children || [];
    this[a.parent].children.push(this[a.id]);
}, { 0: { children: tree } });

console.log(tree);
```

Proposal for unsorted data witch maintains the sort order.

```js
var data = [{ 'id': 54, 'parent': 50, 'order': 7 }, { 'id': 53, 'parent': 50, 'order': 6 }, { 'id': 49, 'parent': 48, 'order': 2 }, { 'id': 51, 'parent': 48, 'order': 4 }, { 'id': 52, 'parent': 0, 'order': 5 }, { 'id': 48, 'parent': 0, 'order': 1 }, { 'id': 50, 'parent': 0, 'order': 3 }, ],
    tree = function (data) {
        var r = [], o = { 0: { children: r } };
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            var p = 0,
                temp = { id: a.id, parent: a.parent, order: a.order };
            if (o[a.id] && o[a.id].children) {
                temp.children = o[a.id].children;
            }
            o[a.id] = temp;
            o[a.parent] = o[a.parent] || {};
            o[a.parent].children = o[a.parent].children || [];                    
            o[a.parent].children.some(function (a) {                        
                if (a.order > temp.order) {
                    return true;
                }
                p++;
            });
            o[a.parent].children.splice(p, 0, temp);
        });
        return r;
    }(data);

console.log(tree);
```

Comment: Thank you for being helpful. Since I cannot gaurantee that the parents will come first, how would you assess the performance considerations of creating an array with only the parents first, then using this method to get the children hooked on?

Comment: there is no problem of speed with this implementation, because of the use of an object as hash table.

Comment: I was able to modify this to fit my specific use case. Thanks for adding it.